# How do I use Java's Scanner class to determine the datatype of my input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, variable-types

[sorry if this is a stupid question, I had a lot of trouble wording it for a google search, and couldn't find any answers to the question, even though it'll probably be like a one-line answer]

I'm just following some tutorials on my Java programming course's website.

Right now I'm coding something that takes will open a prompt screen and be like, "Please enter an integer between 5 and 10: ", and scan the number, and do that for a bunch of different variable types, different boundaries, etc.

Super easy stuff. I just have one small question.

How do I tell my scanning method to check that the variable is of type int? I know it's probably really obvious, but if someone enters "A" or "1.543," I'm supposed to have it display, "That is not an integer!" but I don't know how to actually use the scanner to check variable types

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, because you want to do validation, just read the input in as a String.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Then you want to check that it's a number. You can use the `parse` method, wrapped up in a `try catch`.

```
try{
    int inputDbl = Integer.parseInt(input);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    System.out.println("This is not a number");
}
```

And if you want to do it in a loop, add this `try catch` to a method that returns a `boolean`..

```
public boolean isNumeric(String input)
{
    try{
        double inputDbl = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it better to use hasNextInt() since it doesn't make use of exceptions?

Comment: why double if it's an int?

Comment: Apologies nachokk. Typo. And `hasNextInt()` only returns a `boolean` if it can find an `int`. Doing it this way opens up for more clever validation, such as removing the decimal point from `double` inputs so the program can still continue. When I'm taking input from the user, I always take it as a `String`, and try to decipher what it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if(scanner.hasNextInt()){ ... }` to see if there is an int next - generally speaking some sequences of characters could be parsed as different types of variables, so you have to use each `hasNextDouble()`, etc function in the order you desire.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the complete documentation, which might have many useful functions you are looking for.